# Ruby on Rails Tutorial - Chapter 11 - getting error on integration test example

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to do Chapter 11 in Ruby on Rails Tutorial book and when I try to do the integration test in Listing 11.33 I get two errors both saying that "param is missing or the value is empty: user".  it then lists two lines in the users controller definition, the first is in reference to the user_params and the second is in reference to the create action in the controller.  I looked at some other questions and based on the answers I tried removing the require(:user) part of the user_params definition and this caused the integration tests to go from having two errors to having failures.  But I don't want to remove the require(:user) from the user_params definition.  Does anyone know why I'm getting this error?  Here is the section of the test where the error is being created:

```
test "valid signup information with account activation" do
get signup_path

assert_difference 'User.count', 1 do
  post users_path, params: { user: { name: "Example User",
      email: "user@example.com",
      password: "password",
      password_confirmation: "password" } }
end
```

and here is the definition for user_params that works except for this test

```
def user_params
params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.  I compared the edition of the tutorial book i am reading online through safari online books with the online edition available for free and found that in that edition they instead use:

```
post users_path, user: { name: "Example User",
```

where the params: { } has been removed from around the user: { } 
this change made the errors go away.